# ERROR CONEXIÓN CONTACT FORM html con php

Tags: php, html, html5

tengo el siguiente codigo de HTML5, CSS y PHP de mi contact-form. 
La pagina me muestra el formulario pero cuando intento hacer una prueba de envío no carga el envío. El botón de LIMPIAR funciona perfecto pero el de ENVIAR no carga, se queda el botón en blanco (se puede apreciar el error en la imagen)

[image: Adjunto imagen]

[image: adjunto imagen 2]

CONTACT.HTML

```
<form action="mail.php" method="POST" class="contact-form">

    <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Name" class="required">

    <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email address" class="contact-form-email required">

    <input type="text" name="subject" placeholder="Subject" class="contact-form-subject">

    <textarea name="message" placeholder="Message" class="required" rows="7"></textarea>

    <div class="response-message"></div>

    <button class="border-button" type="reset" id="reset" name="reset">Limpiar</button>
    <button class="border-button" type="submit" id="submit" name="submit">Enviar</button>
```

MAIL.PHP

```
<?php $name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$message = $_POST['message'];
$formcontent="From: $name \n Message: $message";
$recipient = "sa*********@*******.com";
$subject = "Contact Form";
$mailheader = "From: $email \r\n";
mail($recipient, $subject, $formcontent, $mailheader) or die("Error!");
echo "Thank You!";
?>
```

Comment: Significa que está deshabilitado? Si es así, alguna parte de tu código debe hacer eso, el navegador por defecto los tiene todos habilitados

Comment: @Piyin No se si esta deshabilitado o no. Me dijeron que tengo que hacer la configuracion de SMTP, puede ser?

Comment: ¿Tenés un servidor web corriendo? En la imagen que adjuntas la url indica que abriste el html directamente.

Comment: Al principio tienes el botón de enviar visualmente normal (como el limpiar) y al dar clic cambia a ese diseño pero no hace nada? Puedes revisar el DOM de la página porfa, en el botón de enviar da clic derecho > Inspeccionar elemento y muéstranos una captura de pantalla de loq ue te sale en el DOM porfa

Comment: Y es cierto lo que menciona @Asero82 revisalo por favor

Comment: Para saber si está deshabilitado o no, has clic derecho sobre él y luego "Inspeccionar elemento". Si vez que dice "disabled" está deshabilitado

Comment: @user2930137 edite la publicacion con la captura de pantalla.

Comment: @Asero82 tengo online un index con un contador , con el mismo formato de pagina. Pero estoy editando la web por offline

Comment: En inspeccionar elemento me dice "jquery-1.11.3.min.js:5 XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///home/salvatore/Escritorio/FMT/mail.php. Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https.

Comment: Y ya lo estás corriendo en un servidor php? Me suena a que es eso.